# Java: Can we cast a set into an arraylist ?

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, set, type-conversion

I have a `hashmap` called `gg`. I want to take out its keys using `keySet()` method and pass them as parameter of another method.

```
method_A( gg.keySet());

public void method_A(ArrayList<Integer> jj){
 ....
}
```

But I got this error:
`error: incompatible types: Set<Integer> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>`.

Then I saw this:

`method_A (new ArrayList<Integer>(gg.keySet()));`

What is it doing actually ? It looks like type casting to me. I am puzzled. Could someone explain to me what is going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new ArrayList<Integer>(gg.keySet())` is not type casting. It's more like a copy constructor (though actual copy constructors usually take an argument of the same type that is being instantiated, which is not the case here).

It's creating a new `ArrayList<Integer>` instance using the constructor that accepts a `Collection` as an argument. It adds all the elements found in the `Collection` to the new `ArrayList`.

Here's the doc of that constructor :

```
   /**
     * Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified
     * collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's
     * iterator.
     *
     * @param c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
     */
    public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Comment: So, it is in some sense applying an iterator to take out all the elements in a particular collection and add them into an arraylist. Am I correct ? In addition, I want to ask how do I interpret `<? extends E> c` ?

Comment: In addition, I want to ask how do I interpret `<? extends E> c` ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF It means that in order to create an instance of `ArrayList<E>` with this constructor, you can pass any `Collection<T>` instance such that `T` extends or implements `E`.